# Need help for creating criteria subquery

Tags: java, mysql, jpa

I'm beginner in jpa and i encountered with composite query.
Then I started search solution. Many people advised use criteria API.

And so the question: how create similar query using criteriaQuery?

**MySQL version**

```
SELECT role FROM Role WHERE id_role=(SELECT id_role FROM Client WHERE email=:email)
```

**Role**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="role")
public class Role {

@Id
public int id_role;

private enum  enumRole {ADMIN, CLIENT}

@Column(name="role")
private  enumRole role;

public Role() {
}

public Role(enumRole role) {
    this.role = role;
}

public String getRole() {
    return this.role.name();
}

public void setRole(String role) {
    this.role = enumRole.valueOf(role);
}
@OneToMany(targetEntity = Client.class)
private List clientList;
}
```

**Client**

```
@Entity
@Table(name ="client")
public class Client {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
public  Long Id;

@Column(name="first_name", length = 25)
private String firstName;

@Column(name="surname", length = 25)
private String surName;

@Column(name="password", length = 30)
private String password;
@Column(name="email")
private String email;

@Column(name="username", length = 15)
private String username;

public Client() {
}

@ManyToMany(targetEntity = Ticket.class)
private Set ticketSet;

public Client(String firstName, String surName, String password, String email, String username) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.surName = surName;
    this.password = password;
    this.email = email;
    this.username = username;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getSurName() {
    return surName;
}

public void setSurName(String surName) {
    this.surName = surName;
}


public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you not create a mapping between Client and Role? Either a @OneToMany or @ManyToMany?  If so then you dont need to write any sql and could do this with a simple JPA Query method http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-creation

Comment: i think here need mapping. @OneToMany in Role entity.

Comment: With that mapping in place you can then inside your roleRepository just do something like: 

    @Query("select r from Role r left join r.clients c where c.email = :email") 
    Role findOneByClientsEmail(@Param("email") String email);

Comment: but at the moment I would like to do this using the criteria API